# SQL Assembly Error - Permissions in SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, .net-assembly

What is this and how do I fix it:

```
  An error occurred in the Microsoft .NET Framework while trying to load assembly id 65816. The server may be running out of resources, or the assembly may not be trusted with PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE. Run the query again, or check documentation to see how to solve the assembly trust issues. For more information about this error:
```

Comment: what is this and how did you encountered this ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it out http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918040